# Mandrill extension error

Tags: mandrill, bounce

I have civicrm 4.6.5 running on Drupal 7.38 with the Mandrill 2 extension for bulk email. 
I set up a webhook in mandrill to speak to civi and I sent a test bulk email (including fake email addresses) with mandrill to make sure it all works. 
It all works fine except that Mandrill has been sending me 6 bounce notifications per ever since that email which included 1 fake email address.

mandrill posts this error under the webhook :
Error: POST to https://www.msite.org/civicrm/ajax/mte/callback?mandrillSecret=*********989c failed with 500:

Drupal posts :Notice: Undefined index: event in CRM_Mte_BAO_Mandrill::processMandrillCalls() (line 84 of /srv/bindings/.../code/sites/all/extensions/biz.jmaconsulting.mte-2.0/CRM/Mte/BAO/Mandrill.php).

Answer (score 1):

Could this bug be your issue: https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.mte/issues/93

Answer (score 0):

It happening due to fake mail id. You are getting 6 time same error because it will configure in mandrill account to send mail in maximum 6 attempt.

To avoid this error please validate the email id before sending the mail.